SEGV using Eigen on Apple Silicon
I am using the Eigen library in a project of mine. On various architectures and OS this works perfectly (Windows x86, Ubuntu x86, Ubuntu ARM). However, on Apple Silicon using the Clang compiler, I get a SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal.
The error is reported as (using AddressSanitizer):
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==24664==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x00010275e104 bp 0x00016d82f670 sp 0x00016d82f620 T0)
==24664==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==24664==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x10275e104 in Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>, 1, 0>::run(Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>&) AssignEvaluator.h:518
    #1 0x10275dc14 in void Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>>(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>&, Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> const&) AssignEvaluator.h:785
    #2 0x10275d6a4 in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>> const&) PlainObjectBase.h:594
    #3 0x102ca7a2c in my_lib::sim::OutputSupportingSimulation::doOutputValues(my_lib::sim::OutputConfiguration const&, std::__1::array<long, 8ul> const&, std::__1::array<double, 17ul> const&, int) OutputSupportingSimulation.h:479
...

or, using lldb:
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Use of out-of-scope stack memory
  * frame #0: 0x0000000101fd5060 libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__asan::AsanDie()
    frame #1: 0x0000000101feee24 libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__sanitizer::Die() + 192
    frame #2: 0x0000000101fd2f54 libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__asan::ScopedInErrorReport::~ScopedInErrorReport() + 1124
    frame #3: 0x0000000101fd222c libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__asan::ReportGenericError(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, unsigned int, bool) + 1460
    frame #4: 0x0000000101fd3748 libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`__asan_report_load8 + 56
    frame #5: 0x00000001002153a4 my_tests`Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>, 1, 0>::run(Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>&) [inlined] Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>::assignCoeff(this=<unavailable>, a=<unavailable>, b=<unavailable>) const at AssignmentFunctors.h:24:104 [opt]
    frame #6: 0x000000010021539c my_tests`Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>, 1, 0>::run(Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>&) [inlined] Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>::assignCoeff(this=<unavailable>, index=<unavailable>) at AssignEvaluator.h:660:15 [opt]
    frame #7: 0x0000000100215370 my_tests`Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, 0>, 1, 0>::run(kernel=<unavailable>) at AssignEvaluator.h:518:14 [opt]
    frame #8: 0x0000000100214dac my_tests`void Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>>(dst=<unavailable>, src=<unavailable>, func=<unavailable>) at AssignEvaluator.h:785:3 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x00000001002147f8 my_tests`Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>> const&) [inlined] Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, void>::run(dst=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, src=None, func=<unavailable>) at AssignEvaluator.h:954:5 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x00000001002147ec my_tests`Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>> const&) [inlined] void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>>(dst=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, src=None, func=<unavailable>) at AssignEvaluator.h:890:3 [opt]
    frame #11: 0x00000001002147ec my_tests`Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>> const&) [inlined] Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::_set_noalias<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(this=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, other=None) at PlainObjectBase.h:797:7 [opt]
    frame #12: 0x00000001002147c0 my_tests`Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(this=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, other=None) at PlainObjectBase.h:594:7 [opt]
    frame #13: 0x00000001007a2f8c my_tests`my_lib::sim::OutputSupportingSimulation::doOutputValues(my_lib::sim::OutputConfiguration const&, std::__1::array<long, 8ul> const&, std::__1::array<double, 17ul> const&, int) [inlined] Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(this=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, other=None) at Matrix.h:423:9 [opt]
    frame #14: 0x00000001007a2f84 my_tests`my_lib::sim::OutputSupportingSimulation::doOutputValues(my_lib::sim::OutputConfiguration const&, std::__1::array<long, 8ul> const&, std::__1::array<double, 17ul> const&, int) [inlined] Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::IndexedView<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Array<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::SingleRange>>(this=rows: 0, cols: 0
[ ]
, other=None) at Matrix.h:424:5 [opt]
    frame #15: 0x00000001007a2f84 my_tests`my_lib::sim::OutputSupportingSimulation::doOutputValues(this=<unavailable>, oc=<unavailable>, intvalues=<unavailable>, doublevalues=<unavailable>, streamIdx=<unavailable>) at OutputSupportingSimulation.h:479:49 [opt]

where the relevant lines from my code, up and including OutputSupportingSimulation.h:479 looks like this:
...

Eigen::ArrayXi nIndices = this->msdMeasuredIndices[msdIdx];
Eigen::VectorXd relCoords = this->getCoordinates();
assert(nIndices.minCoeff() >= 0 && nIndices.maxCoeff() < relCoords.size());
Eigen::VectorXd relCoordsSubset = relCoords(nIndices); // <- line 479


Is this a known bug? Am I missing some compiler incompatibilities?
I will update this question when I manage to produce a minimum reproducing example.
Some further system information:

Apple M3 Pro, 12 Core
Eigen 3.4.0

with

Homebrew clang version 18.1.8, arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0

or/and

AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309


If using homebrew clang, did you follow the instructions that homebrew gave you after LLVM was installed?

Specifically: To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:     LDFLAGS="-L$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -L$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/llvm/lib -lunwind"

@sweenish yes, I did. However, noteably, I get the same segfault with AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309

That's a data point worth [edit]ing into the question.

Finally, it's fairly trivial to run the program through a debugger and get a stack trace of the crash. There is always the possibility that the error lies elsewhere, and the stack trace is a fairly straightforward way to see if that's the case.

@sweenish the stacktrace from lldb is the pretty much the same as given by AddressSanitizer; in particular, the same line of my code is the origin. I have added it to the question.

A sad truism of C++ is when you're dealing with a memory access error, the actual bug that resulted in the access error is often nowhere near the crash site. In this case obviously something operated on a null and the backtraces show no visible nulls being passed, that null could be coming from anywhere.

Ok, so assuming @user4581301 is correct and the error is anywhere. How can I locate it? Are there compiler flags that can throw errors on operation on null?

If you aren't already, turn on UBSan to see if it can spot a mistake that's leading to... well anything it spots you'll want to fix. With ASan, since you're already using it, that should look like -fsanitize=address,undefined on the command line. If you're lucky and have reverse debugger support, turn it on, wait for the crash, and start stepping backward to see where the er is coming from. If you can at least pick off the bad variable with the debugger, that may be a start. You can brute force track the variable name through the code and place breakpoints at likely spots.

The hope is that if you had something truly rogue, some pointer somewhere out there or a buffer overflow that's smashing other people's memory, that ASan or UBSan already spotted it.

But no direct "signal on null" flag that I know of. It would be pretty much unworkable since storing null is valid a lot of the time. Many programs would trip the alarm far too often. And trying to access null, that's what ASan spotted for you.
